# QGIS takes forever to render ArcGIS World Imagery

Tags: rendering, world-imagery

I'm currently using QGIS 3.16.5. I am using the ArcGIS World Imagery - High Resolution 30cm Imagery layer to select training data for land cover classification. For the last two months, I was able to zoom into the layer at the scale of 1:936 and rendering happened pretty quickly. This morning, my QGIS crashed and after that, QGIS takes forever to render the layer when zooming in (even at higher scale like 1:1575). I have come crossed a few posts on speeding up QGIS rendering, and have made sure that the "use render caching","render layers in parallel" and "simplification" are turned on. I have also installed the new release (3.22.6) but the issue persisted. My colleague also tested on his computer which has QGIS 3.18 and the same thing happened. So I'm not sure if it's a bug with QGIS or if there is something wrong with the ArcGIS Map Service.

On another note, when I started QGIS I got this error message:

> WARNING    Traceback (most recent call last):
> File "C:/PROGRA~1/QGIS3~1.16/apps/qgis-ltr/./python/plugins\processing\script\ScriptAlgorithmProvider.py",
> line 121, in loadAlgorithms
> alg = ScriptUtils.loadAlgorithm(moduleName, filePath)
> File "C:/PROGRA~1/QGIS3~1.16/apps/qgis-ltr/./python/plugins\processing\script\ScriptUtils.py", line 66, in loadAlgorithm
> spec.loader.exec_module(module)
> File "", line 728, in exec_module
> File "", line 219, in _call_with_frames_removed
> File "C:\Users\AllieNguyen\AppData\Roaming\QGIS\QGIS3\profiles\default\processing\scripts\test.py",
> line 4, in
> grid = QgsProject.instance().mapLayersByName("Grid")[0]
> IndexError: list index out of range

I wonder if the rendering issue has something to do with this error. Because when I set the "max cores to use" or changed the "simplification threshold" and click OK, this message showed up again.

[image]

Comment: *How* were you accessing the Arc imagery?

Comment: I create a connection by Open Data Source Manager > ArcGIS Map Service > New and use this URL: http://server.arcgisonline.com/arcgis/rest/services/World_Imagery/MapServer. After that, I click Connect and select the layer I want (High Resolution 30cm Imagery) and click Add.

Comment: Try a fresh profile and see if the issue persists - https://www.northrivergeographic.com/archives/qgis-profiles https://docs.qgis.org/testing/en/docs/user_manual/introduction/qgis_configuration.html#working-with-user-profiles

Comment: Thanks. I have tried with a fresh profile but the issue persists. Also I have installed QGIS 3.16.5 on another laptop to check but the same thing happened. Another colleague of mine test on her laptop with QGIS 3.10 and also the same thing happened. I think it's a systematic issue of some sort and will report a bug.

Comment: I have found a solution. Turns out that the path to the server has changed to: https://services.arcgisonline.com/ArcGIS/rest/services/World_Imagery/MapServer. I found this new path in the URL box on the webpage: https://www.arcgis.com/home/item.html?id=10df2279f9684e4a9f6a7f08febac2a9. Once I used this path to connect, the rendering resumed to (almost) normal speed. Thanks everyone for your kind help!